# Is there a way to get rid of brief BrowserComponent white flash during form in/out transition?

Tags: codenameone

One of my `Form` contains a BrowserComponent. My `Form` has a non-white bcakground color (when Dark Mode is on)

No matter what I set the browser's background color to, when I `showBack()` the previous `Form`, a brief flash is shown in the space the `BrowserComponent` occupies

Here is a video showing this on iOS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKDu5.jpg

On Android, the effect is slightly different. The space the `BrowserComponent` occupies is initially drawn white/gray/black (randomly) while the `Form` is in transition (in & out)

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a bug in browser component that was probably missed due to the default background color. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) with this. If you can isolate this to a test case for that issue it would help too.

It looks like `createPeerImage` in the iOS port should accept a background color but it might be something else.

Comment: I looked at both iOS and Android native code for this and it's a bit above my current CN1 level (first time I look at a PeerComponent). I filed an issue... hope someone more knowledgeable can look into this. Edit: I will add a test case to github soon